# how do I add a like box and like button to my page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to implement the Facebook "Like" button for my website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854051/how-to-implement-the-facebook-like-button-for-my-website)

I'm not understanding the "get started" directions for adding a like button and a like page to my page. can someone help me out?

Comment: What in the get started is it that you don't understand?

Answer (score 0):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Like Button HTML

```
<script>(function(d){
  var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=172873559454230&xfbml=1";
  d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
}(document));</script>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="URL_GOES_HERE" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

What do you mean by like page?